# Convert /etc/ethers to /etc/dhcpd.conf

Tags: linux, dhcp, dnsmasq

I needed to convert dnsmasq based DHCP server configuration to ISC dhcpd, so it was necessary to transfer a large bunch of fixed IP addresses to the new format.

The input format is:

```
84:2b:2b:19:05:a7 192.168.14.6
00:50:56:00:00:07 192.168.14.7
...
```

The output needs to be something like:

```
host myhost1 {
  hardware ethernet 84:2b:2b:19:05:a7
  fixed address 192.168.14.6
}
```

Hostname should be resolved through reverse DNS query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample python script (code is longer for the purpose of clarity):

```
import socket
import re
import sys

ethers_file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
for line in ethers_file:
    values = line.split()
    mac = None
    ip = None
    if len(values) >=1 and re.match( r'^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$',values[0]) :
       mac = values[0]
    if len(values) >=2 and re.match( r'^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$',values[1]) :
       ip = values[1]
    hostname = None
    if (mac is not None and ip is not None) :
        try:
            resolve_values = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
            hostname = resolve_values[0];
        except:
            hostname = "host_" + ip.replace("\\.","_")
    if (mac is not None and ip is not None) :
        print "host " + hostname + " {"
        print "  hardware ethernet " + mac
        print "  fixed address " + ip
        print "}"
ethers_file.close()
```